# Syntax highlighting of code snippets in a web page "google-code-prettify" not working

Tags: html, prettify, google-code-prettify

I have following code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="../../../Styles/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../../Scripts/prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>And from code behind write following :</p>

<pre class="prettyprint">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblLoading.Text = "Loading News...";
        }
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to see code syntax at the result. What have I missed?

The result is like this:

[image]

An online demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/yKss3/

Comment: Are you sure the paths to the CSS and JS files are correct?

Comment: can you please check if your path to css and js are correct ? your code looks pretty ok for google - code - prettifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
<body>
```

to

```
<body onload="prettyPrint()">
```

[Prettify's README file](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) says:

> 1. Download a distribution
> 2. Include the script and stylesheets in your document (you will need to make sure the css and js file are on your server, and adjust the paths in the script and link tag)
>       `<link href="prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`
>       `<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>`
> 3. **Add `onload="prettyPrint()"` to your document's `body` tag.**
> 4. Modify the stylesheet to get the coloring you prefer

Comment: @ Mike , yes, you're right..how could i put line numbers and copy functionality?

Comment: @James, See http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html#linenums for line numbers.

Comment: @James if you read the README file that Mike provided, it tells you how to put line numbers in